# Where should I get started to create a node command line script to copy a base website like express

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, express, generator

So this question revolves around the command line and node.js. I know using express app creates a folder named app loaded with files ready to run npm install and then node app.js

What I would like to do is create something similar, but use my configuration. I use handlebars for my templating system instead of Jade and have structured my folders nicely for base project. I currently have to copy and paste my folder, but I know there is a better way to do this.

Thanks again Guru Masters!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It essentially boils down to writing an app that creates / copies files and directories, adding some custom data to some of them. Most of the things you need to achieve that can be found in the [file system module](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html).

You could take a look at the source code to the express app to see how they do it.

Alternatively you could look at [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), which covers this (and a few other things) in a more generic way. The specific bit for setting up a new project from a template is a [generator](http://yeoman.io/generators.html) and they have [instructions on how to write your own](http://yeoman.io/generators.html#writing-your-first-generator-again).

Comment: Thanks, saved me tons of time searching around. I was pretty lost. This Yeoman looks really nice. Which method do you normally use?